# What kind of data obtained from a paypal transaction I should store inside my local database?

Tags: database, paypal, transactions, paypal-ipn, eclipse-pdt

Which informations obtained from  IPN you should keep inside your local Database ?

Is the `$_POST['txn_id']` field the only field needed to assure you a retrack of all the transaction informations from paypal? Or is it better to insert all informations obtained from the IPN/PDT postback?

Basically i'm trying to figure out wich info I need to store in case of a transaction problem and/or a user complaint.

Comment: Paypal integration manual will help.Store payment reference information, corresponding user information. Well, it's up to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `txn_id` isn't enough. According to the documentation PayPal provides on their [Introducing IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) page

> Verify that the IPN is not a duplicate. To do this, save the
>   transaction ID and last payment status in each IPN message in a
>   database and verify that the current IPN's values for these fields are
>   not already in this database. Note: You can't rely on transaction ID
>   alone to screen out duplicates, as this scenario shows: 1) PayPal
>   sends you an IPN notifying you of a pending payment. 2) PayPal later
>   sends you a second IPN telling you that the payment has completed.
>   However, both IPNs contain the same transaction ID; therefore, if you
>   were using just transaction ID to identify IPNs, you would to treat
>   the "completed payment" IPN as a duplicate.

At a minimum, according to this you need to story the **transaction ID** and **last payment status**. It's also a good idea to store information you may need to audit against PayPal if there is ever a discrepancy payments you receive versus what you think you should receive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, according to paypal docs and your answer I'm implementing a system that stores the data of every IPN I receive and relate it to the specific user purchase, when the status of a transaction changes to _completed_ or  other statuses then I proceed to update the relative user local data.  This allows me to track every transaction update for every user and have a complete overview of the pending/completed transactions.